# How can I make sure that my code runs properly all the time

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code running smoothly when I step through the code (F8), but when I run it with F5 or call it to run from a button it doesn't do what it's supposed to. It only does the lookup in the first cell (Q2) and leaves the rest blank - like it skipped to run the formula down to the last row.

How can I improve my code to make sure that it always runs as it should?

```
Sub LookupFilename()
' Looks up the filename to be set according to Team Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Controller!C9:C12,4,FALSE),""Other"")"
    Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Successful data collection.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Cells` and `Rows` in `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`, which may or may not be the one you want (though all of your `Range` calls also implicitly refer to the `Activesheet`, so maybe it is what you think).

Comment: Like BigBen said; you want to refer to the `LastRow` of the intended sheet. If you have another sheet active, it may not be setting the last row properly. Is your button on a separate sheet or are you running the macro from a different sheet by chance? `ActiveSheet` requires that the intended sheet be selected.

Comment: @BigBen, yes the formula should be placed in the active sheet (Q2 down to the last row).

Comment: Then what does `Debug.Print LastRow` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: `Debug.Print LastRow` gives me 8, the last row of my sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to `Select` or use `ActiveCell` or `AutoFill`. Replace:

```
Range("Q2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Controller!C9:C12,4,FALSE),""Other"")"
Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)
```

with:

```
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Controller!C9:C12,4,FALSE),""Other"")"
```

Note, you shouldn't be `Activate`ing either. Instead, *qualify* your `Range`, `Cells`, and `Rows` calls with the appropriate worksheet. Note the `.` before `Cells`, `Rows` and `Range` below:

```
Dim Data As Worksheet
Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

With Data
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],Controller!C9:C12,4,FALSE),""Other"")"
End With
```

Comment: thanks.. this works but when called from a button it does the same issue. i've update my code to activate the sheet where the formula should run and it still has the same issue.

Comment: Don't `Activate` the sheet either. *Qualify* your `Range` and `Cells` and `Rows` calls with the worksheet in question, as I've demonstrated in an edit.

Comment: it debugs on this line `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: With an error message of?

Comment: right, says run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Do you still have the `Set Data = ...` line?

Comment: no, i removed it as recommended.

Comment: You need `Set Data = ...` before you use `With Data`.